# WEB API DELETE request causes internal server error 500 with 0 length content

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I have created a Microsoft Web API with a number of controllers. On my local machine (Win 7, IIS Express) testing one of the controllers everything works fine. I can delete a "make" object with id 1 using the request localhostetc/makes/1. When I deploy to the server (W2K8, IIS7.5) I get a 500 error on the same request - see http://api.carsnow.ie/makes/1

My question is not what is causing the error, but what is the error? I can't see the details as I get a 0 length response. Earlier I was getting a custom error but at some stage when trying to see the underlying stack trace I lost even that.

So far I have tried the following....

I turned CustomErrors to "Off" in web.config

I added this code to WebAPIConfig.cs - http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/

I added

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

to Global.asax

I turned on detailed errors in IIS7

Comment: I also added <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/> to config file

Comment: you might want to put an uber try/catch block on your delete API just for the purpose of finding the root cause and send back the error message in the response OR log it to know it. for production scenarios, it is recommended that a generic 500 error comes back, possibly with an error id and not any more info for security reasons. iis 7 and above enforce this.

Comment: I tried this, but still get the error - which suggests to me that the issue is with the serialisation routines or something else that is not directly caused by the code within the controller.

Comment: I also tried what you probably meant but I missed your meaning - which was a global try-catch on the whole application. That also did not work as the issue was with IIS as far as I can make out. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this will work for everyone but in the end I was able to force the hand of IIS by deleting the setting for a 500 custom error pages in the "Error Pages" setting of the website in IIS. It appears that when it couldn't find the template for the custom error it spat out the real error.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default) should help you:

> In earlier versions of IIS, error messages from classic ASP scripts
>   were sent to a Web browser, by default. Because these error messages
>   might reveal sensitive information to malicious users, IIS 7 and above
>   disables this feature by default. When your classic ASP scripts
>   encounter an error in IIS, you receive the following error message by
>   default:
>
> ```
> An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
>
> If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.
> ```

Comment: I'm using .Net Framework 4.5 - not classic ASP. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Disregard that part of the article, the IIS configuration should be valid for your setup...